# rounding, logical error in approx.df in R Program

Tags: r, numeric, linear-programming, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I am trying a solve a question. When I run this code I achieved what did I want.(.8372e-03 1.8372e-06 1.8372e-09)

```
truncation.error <- function(f, x) {
  steps <- c(0.1, 0.01, 0.001)
  n <- length(steps)
  fdx1 <- vector(length = n)
  for (h in 1:n) {
    fdx1[h] <- exp(2.4)*steps[h]^3/6
  }
  return(fdx1)
}
for (i in 2.4) {
  print(truncation.error(f, x))}
```

However when I write in data.frame format like it the output for truncation.error is 0-0-0. 
why the output changed? Any idea? and how can I fixed this problem. I want to see true answer which I achieved in above.
 ;

````
colnames(approx.df) <- c('Actual Values', 'Central Difference Approx', 'Central Differences Error', "truncation error")

approx.df```



Original question is [ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmO3I.png][1]


How can I solve this problem or where am I making mistake? Thanks a lot.


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmO3I.png
````

Comment: change f <- expression(exp(x))  it to f <- as.expression(exp(x)) . your error will be gone

Comment: Thank you so much. But now the outputs are rounded to zero. How can I  take real results. Which are 0.00183720-0.0000084 and 0.00000002

Comment: can you tell me why you are using  fdx1<-vector(length=n)

Comment: I added the original question in above. The problem in the 3rd part. (Truncation error part). I tried to write it according to how did I find central differences. Which is  ` f <- function(x) {
return(exp(x))}
central.difference <- function(f, x) {
steps <- c(0.1, 0.01, 0.001)
n <- length(steps)
fdx <- vector(length = n)
for (h in 1:n) {
fdx[h] <- (f(x+ steps[h]) - f(x - steps[h])) / (steps[h]*2)
 }
 return(fdx)
}
for (i in x) {
print(central.difference(f, 2.3))
}`. So actually I don't know why did I use fdx1<-vector(length=n) . Just trying to solve it.Shouldn't I use?

Comment: i tried to replicate the complete code and fdx1 is giving logical anser true and false because of that  your final answer comes out as 0

Comment: I fixed it but I don't know-how. It works now.When I print it answer come out as true. I really don't know how to use R sorry for that. Thanks a lot for your help. And here  my last question. When I print this code, the answer comes out what should suppose to be so it is true. (0.00183720...)                                                                       however when I define something like that approx.df <- data.frame(cbind(actual, central.approx, actual - central.approx,round(truncation.error(f,5)))) the output shows again as just 0. Do you have any idea for that ?

Comment: can you provide me reproducible code with  dput()  i will  try to help you after that . Also in the above code you need to provide decimel places in round

Comment: I would like to but I don't know how to use dput(). But here is the actual code "truncation.error <- function(f, x) {
  steps <- c(0.1, 0.01, 0.001)
  n <- length(steps)
  fdx1 <- vector(length = n)
  for (h in 1:n) {
    fdx1[h] <- exp(2.4)*steps[h]^3/6
  }
  return(fdx1)
}
for (i in 2.4) {
  print(truncation.error(f, x))}approx.df <- data.frame(cbind(actual, central.approx, actual - central.approx,round(truncation.error(f,5))))
 colnames(approx.df) <- c('Actual Values', 'Central Difference Approx', 'Central Differences Error', "truncation error")
approx.df.   "

Comment: Mistake you are doing is you are not defining these things actual, central.approx, actual - central.approx  where are these variabes saved or defined in your code?

Comment: f <- function(x) {
return(exp(x))
 }
central.difference <- function(f, x) {
  steps <- c(0.1, 0.01, 0.001)
  n <- length(steps)
  fdx <- vector(length = n)
  for (h in 1:n) {
    fdx[h] <- (f(x+ steps[h]) - f(x - steps[h])) / (steps[h]*2)
  }
  return(fdx)
}
for (i in x) {
  print(central.difference(f, 2.3))
}fdx <- function(x) {
  return(exp(x) )
}
actual <- vector(length = length(x))
central.approx <- c(9.99081, 9.97435, 9.97418)
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  actual[i] <- fdx(x[i])
}  it is first part of my code . I defined here. After that I passed to truncation.error part

Comment: Oooo you are right. I defined truncation error in where did I defined central.difference and actual. It worked Now my output is fixed. Thank you so much four your kind help.

Comment: your welcome and please marked it as closed or answered one i add a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`change f <- expression(exp(x)) it to f <- as.expression(exp(x))` . your error will be gone
 and Mistake you are doing is you are not defining these things actual, central.approx, actual - central.approx where are these variabes saved or defined in your code?